# An unlocked wallet is holding 100% of the lp

Tags: uniswap, pancakeswap, liquidity-provider

[image]

How to remove the inscription An unlocked wallet is holding 100% of the lp on poocoin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were advised the site, try blocking through my code openlock.io/ref/31 - will be much better for you

Answer (score 2):

To remove this inscription, you need to lock your liquidity of the token, for this you can use, for example, openlock.io (I blocked it myself), or another contract.

Comment: Thanks it seems to be working

Comment: please, happy to help